# If y = x is a linear function and y is linear function then can x as the argument is also a function?

Tags: functions

Sorry for asking this stupid kindergarden question.
If we have a linear function like $y = x$ then $y$ is the linear function but there is $x$ which is also a variable. When I have $x = 1$ then $y = 1$ does it mean that $x$ is also a linear function ? Which means that $y = x$ has a function $y$ with a function $x$ ? I know it doesn't make sense a bit. I had problem understandint a bit stuff because I heard there is a small difference in $f(x) = x$ and $y = x$. Then f(x) and y are the output of the linear function, so does this $x$ is also a function ? But what is this hidden function in $x$ ?

I'll try to repeat it.
For $y = x$ when I give a value $x = 1$ then $y = 1$ they are practically the same so $x$ itself is a function ? So function $y = x$ and function $x$ are the same ? I hear that single letter could also be a function so maybe $y=x$ has two functions in him, a linear y and linear x, because it looks like $x$ is also a function.

Comment: The inverse of the identity function is the identity function

Comment: The equation $y = x$ is just an equation, not so much a function. It shows how two variables are related to each other. We often will interpret such equations, particularly of the form $y = \text{some expression involving $x$}$ as a function, and there's nothing stopping us from treating this equation as $x = \text{some expression involving $y$}$ and interpreting $x$ as a function of $y$. And yes, if $x$ is a linear function of some other variable(s), e.g. $t$, then $y$ is also a linear function of $t$. In fact, it's the same function of $t$!

Comment: @TheoBendit But then there is next variable "t" which can also be a function and it would be endless. Darn it ... I just saw in the books and in the websites that y = x and f(x) = x mean the same or that they don't mean the same. I thought that both of them are the functions. But my main problem was that the "x" is only an input. So now y = x and we give x a value x = 1 and now y = 1 but what does it mean that I gave value to "x" ? What is "x" ? A function, something ? Why do we interpret "x" if y is a function that this "x" is not a function but an input/variable that we can give a value.

Comment: But if do something like this z = x then y = z then what? "z" is a input/variable ? Even if we know "z" is a function ? I give just value to "z" like it is not a function ? So what if "x" has a hidden function ? That I give value ? I don't get it. Also I know y = x so value of "x" will be equal to "y" but if "x" is a "hidden value" then y is a function of a function "x" that take value depending on out liking and doesn't come from an equation like y =x. 
Sorry for overcomplicating it please don't down vote this post ...

Comment: PS. Like there is y = x and single "x" without any equal sign. Then I give a value to this "x" 
then this single "x" has now a sign x = 1 but before didn't have, and y = 1 because x = 1 for their equation. So single "x" is a function so in y = x,  "y" and "x" are both linear functions, but we don't give value to "y" but to "x" so what is "x" is it a function or what ? Darn it .... Both y = x and "x" have the same result with different letters but are also a bit different I don't get it. Help ;(

Comment: @TheoBendit Am I wrong ? I got a bit lost

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are considered as "variables". A "variable" is not really a formal, mathematical concept, in the sense that "$x$ is a variable" is not a statement that can be encoded mathematically. It cannot be proven or disproven. Instead, it says something about how we **interpret** equations like $y = x$. By saying "$x$ and $y$ are variables" we are claiming or possibly defining a relationship between unknown quantities. In elementary mathematics, $y = x$ is often considered a definition of a function, meaning something similar to $f(x) = x$ (but naming it with $y$, rather than $f$).

Comment: But, it could also refer to a set of points, in particular, it could refer to the line of points in the plane. Specifically, the set of points whose coordinates $(x,y)$ satisfy $x=y$. In other words, points of the form $(x,x)$. It also could be a definition of the symbol $y$, in terms of the symbol $x$, i.e. we have a new symbol $y$, and we will use it in lieu of writing "$x$" (though, this seems unlikely, given "$y$" is no simpler than writing "$x$"). To tell the difference, you need context! Read what the author says, and if they're clear, they'll tell you which it is.

Comment: Asking if they're linear functions is confusing without said context. Yes, the function $f(x) = x$ is a linear function. If we have $y = x$, i.e. the relationship between variables $y$ and $x$ is given by the function $f$, i.e. $y = f(x)$, then this would mean that "$y$ depends linearly on $x$", or "$y$ is a linear function of $x$". If $x$ is a linear function of something else (the $t$ from several comments ago, but it could be anything), then $y$ will also be a linear function of that variable $t$, since the composition of linear functions is linear.

Comment: @TheoBendit Usually when I have equations I have to interpret by myself, like y = x it a function or y =  x^2 + 1 etc. But there was one part that was very interesting. That y depends linearly on x, but does something depends on x ? Like you've mentioned with "t", but if there is no equation for "x" that depends on t, then I have to interpret it as not as a function but as something I can manipulate/give a value, and ignore it that it could be a hidden function that I don't know ?

Comment: So if there is no information about "x" then I  can interpret it as something I give value and not as a function ? And "y" I can interpret as a function ? Because f(x) = x and y = x  is pretty confusing because some says it is the same and some says it is not.

Comment: Also I was just very interested whether if f(x)= x and y = x meant the same then what if "x" was a function and was linear that doesn't have a variable like "t" or anything else, I just give him value  x=1 the result is 1 and y = 1 and the result was 1 so I thought that there was linear function in a linear function, because x received a value that had the same result like y. So when they give the same result and "y" was the output of the function then maybe "x" also is a function. For example sin(x). It is a function but doesn't have the equation like f(x) = x. so it's hard to say how it work

Comment: Like y =  sin(x) it is y which is a function and sin(x) which is also a function, so "x" is a letter that isn't a function but it is something that has a value like y = x in which "y" is a function and "x" is not a function but rather it is just something then.  But what about sin(x) it doesn't have any equation that uses "x". Sorry for the spam

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141713/discussion-between-theo-bendit-and-user331990).

Comment: @TheoBendit What I said in the chat has sense ?
Sorry for taking time

Comment: @user331990 Sorry, I have been busy. You're not off my radar; I just have some things to do. I'm moving country soon! I'll get to you next week.

Comment: @TheoBendit My god that's really a lot to do. Sorry I thought I was forgotten ;) Hope you the best there. I'll try to sustain the chat because it can be locked.